# How to remove comma in moderncv in the education section

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am trying to remove the comma in the education section after the degree. How can I achieve this?

```
\section{Education}

\cventry{Jan 2013--Dec 2018}{Bachelor's of Science in Information Systems}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere, NW}{\textit{}}{}  
\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Business Analyst Nanodegree}{Udacity}{}{\textit{}}{}
```

[image]

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[center]{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75, 
% top=2cm, bottom=2cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}
\linespread{1.1}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{1111 Nowhere Street, Apt 111}{Nowhere, NW}{11111}
\phone[mobile]{(100)-111-1111}
\email{johndoe@johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/]{john-doe}
\social[github][github.com/johndoe]{john-doe}

\title{Business Analysis | Data Analysis | Project Management | Information Systems} %

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% 
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% 
  }%
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    {\centering\textbf{\@title}\\[2em]}%
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother

\raggedbottom %


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Summary}
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.  
\end{itemize} 

\section{Technical Proficiency}
Advanced Microsoft Office Suite (Word, Excel, PowerPoint), Visio, Project 2016, Alteryx, Tableau (Dashboards, Stories), Python, Java, R, SQL, PL/SQL, PostgreSQL, Mode, JIRA, SmartSheet, VirtualBox, Eclipse, WordPress, Adobe Photoshop

\section{Areas of Expertise}
Business Analytics, Business Intelligence, Relationship Building, Predictive Modeling, Regression Analysis, Process Improvement, Project Management, Data Quality Management, User Acceptance Testing, Data Analysis, Visual Modeling

\section{Professional Experience}
\cventry{Mar 2019--Present}{Research Assistant}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere}{}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\newline{}%
Key Contributions:%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\section{Academic Projects}
\cventry{Sept 2018--Dec 2018}{Nowhere Group Relocation}{Project Management}{}{}%
{%\newline{}%
  \begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{itemize}%
}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Visualizing Movie Data}{Data Visualization}{}{}%
{%\newline{}%
  \begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{itemize}%
}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Predicting Impact of New Menu}{A/B Testing}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Forecasting Video Game Sales}{Time-Series Forecasting}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{UMBeats DJ Club}{System Analysis and Design}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{Hotel Management System}{Database Application Management}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\section{Education}
\cventry{Jan 2013--Dec 2018}{Bachelor's of Science in Information Systems}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere, NW}{\textit{}}{}
\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Business Analyst Nanodegree}{Udacity}{}{\textit{}}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your shown code you have an empty `\textit{}` in the 5th bracket of command `\cventry`.  This command is interpreted by the class `moderncv` to **be not empty** and therefore you get the added, unwanted comma.

To get rid of that delete both `\textit{}`:

```
\section{Education}
\cventry{Jan 2013--Dec 2018}{Bachelor's of Science in Information Systems}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere, NW}{}{}  % <===================================================
\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Business Analyst Nanodegree}{Udacity}{}{}{} % <==================
```

The complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[center]{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75, 
% top=2cm, bottom=2cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}
\linespread{1.1}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{1111 Nowhere Street, Apt 111}{Nowhere, NW}{11111}
\phone[mobile]{(100)-111-1111}
\email{johndoe@johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/]{john-doe}
\social[github][github.com/johndoe]{john-doe}

\title{Business Analysis | Data Analysis | Project Management | Information Systems} %

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\}%
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\}}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makehead}% 
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\\[1em]}% 
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    \textbf{\@title}\\[2em]% 
  }%
  {}%
  {}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
  {\par}%
  {%
    \par%
    {\centering\textbf{\@title}\\[2em]}%
  }%
  {}%
  {}
\makeatother

\raggedbottom %


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Summary}
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    \item It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.  
\end{itemize} 

\section{Technical Proficiency}
Advanced Microsoft Office Suite (Word, Excel, PowerPoint), Visio, Project 2016, Alteryx, Tableau (Dashboards, Stories), Python, Java, R, SQL, PL/SQL, PostgreSQL, Mode, JIRA, SmartSheet, VirtualBox, Eclipse, WordPress, Adobe Photoshop

\section{Areas of Expertise}
Business Analytics, Business Intelligence, Relationship Building, Predictive Modeling, Regression Analysis, Process Improvement, Project Management, Data Quality Management, User Acceptance Testing, Data Analysis, Visual Modeling

\section{Professional Experience}
\cventry{Mar 2019--Present}{Research Assistant}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere}{}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\newline{}%
Key Contributions:%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\section{Academic Projects}
\cventry{Sept 2018--Dec 2018}{Nowhere Group Relocation}{Project Management}{}{}%
{%\newline{}%
  \begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{itemize}%
}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Visualizing Movie Data}{Data Visualization}{}{}%
{%\newline{}%
  \begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.     
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \end{itemize}%
}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Predicting Impact of New Menu}{A/B Testing}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Forecasting Video Game Sales}{Time-Series Forecasting}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{UMBeats DJ Club}{System Analysis and Design}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Jan 2018--May 2018}{Hotel Management System}{Database Application Management}{}{}{%\newline{}%
\begin{itemize}%[label=\textcolor{black}{\textbullet}]
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{itemize}}

\section{Education}
\cventry{Jan 2013--Dec 2018}{Bachelor's of Science in Information Systems}{University of Nowhere County}{Nowhere, NW}{}{}  % <===================================================
\cventry{Jun 2018--Sept 2018}{Business Analyst Nanodegree}{Udacity}{}{}{} % <==================

\end{document}
```

gives you then:

[image: resulting page]